# Eliminar salto de línea al input (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como hacer para eliminar el salto de línea entre el input a y b

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo, si te refieres al espacio existe entre el mensaje "Hola Inserta un Núm: " y "Hola inserta otro Núm: " creo que es problema del IDE que usas. A continuación te dejo el mismo ejemplo en un enlace para que lo puedas comprobrar por ti mismo: [Código para verificar](https://repl.it/repls/DazzlingCelebratedYottabyte#main.py). De igual forma, te recomiendo que visites [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para que de esta forma las preguntas que formules sean bien recibidas, y de paso, obtener tú primera medalla!!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, me he estado rompiendo la cabeza, es spyder de Anaconda, voy a ver que hago, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Has podido verificar el ejemplo?. Yo personalmente como IDE uso VSCode pero hay muchas otras alternativas como PyCharm, PyDev para Eclipse o VIM. Saludos

Comment: Si, por eso se me hacia raro que cree salto de línea, voy a ver si utilizo VsCode?
Me lo recomiendas como uno de los mejores?, soy nuevo en esto, carrera de la U...

Comment: Yo personalmente es el que uso. De todas formas, es un tema muy personal, simplemente es cuestión de estar agusto con él y adaptarse, si a lo mejor buscas uno más específico para Python te recomiendo PyCharm. De igual modo, si tienes alguna duda más que no sea necesaria disponer de un post para ello, puedes acceder al siguiente [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217110/python) en el que me encuentro para hablar. Saludos